# How do terminal pipes in Python differ from those in Rust?

Tags: python, audio, rust, ffmpeg, tauri

To work on learning Rust (in a Tauri project) I am converting a Python 2 program that uses ffmpeg to create a custom video format from a GUI. The video portion converts successfully, but I am unable to get the audio to work. With the debugging I have done for the past few days, it looks like I am not able to read in the audio data in Rust correctly from the terminal pipe - what is working to read in the video data is not working for the audio. I have tried reading in the audio data as a string and then converting it to bytes but then the byte array appears empty. I have been researching the 'Pipe'-ing of data from the rust documentation and python documentation and am unsure how the Rust pipe could be empty or incorrect if it's working for the video.

From this [python article](https://www.endpointdev.com/blog/2015/01/getting-realtime-output-using-python/) and this rust [stack overflow exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49733027/how-to-capture-the-output-of-a-process-piped-into-a-rust-program), it looks like the python stdout pipe is equivalent to the rust stdin pipe?

The python code snippet for video and audio conversion:

```python
output=open(self.outputFile, 'wb')
devnull = open(os.devnull, 'wb')

vidcommand = [ FFMPEG_BIN,
            '-i', self.inputFile,
            '-f', 'image2pipe',
            '-r', '%d' % (self.outputFrameRate),
            '-vf', scaleCommand,
            '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
            '-pix_fmt', 'bgr565be',
            '-f', 'rawvideo', '-']
        
vidPipe = '';
if os.name=='nt' :
    startupinfo = sp.STARTUPINFO()
    startupinfo.dwFlags |= sp.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    vidPipe=sp.Popen(vidcommand, stdin = sp.PIPE, stdout = sp.PIPE, stderr = devnull, bufsize=self.inputVidFrameBytes*10, startupinfo=startupinfo)
else:
    vidPipe=sp.Popen(vidcommand, stdin = sp.PIPE, stdout = sp.PIPE, stderr = devnull, bufsize=self.inputVidFrameBytes*10)

vidFrame = vidPipe.stdout.read(self.inputVidFrameBytes)

audioCommand = [ FFMPEG_BIN,
    '-i', self.inputFile,
    '-f', 's16le',
    '-acodec', 'pcm_s16le',
    '-ar', '%d' % (self.outputAudioSampleRate),
    '-ac', '1',
    '-']

audioPipe=''
if (self.audioEnable.get() == 1):
    if os.name=='nt' :
        startupinfo = sp.STARTUPINFO()
        startupinfo.dwFlags |= sp.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
        audioPipe = sp.Popen(audioCommand, stdin = sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr = devnull, bufsize=self.audioFrameBytes*10, startupinfo=startupinfo)
    else:
        audioPipe = sp.Popen(audioCommand, stdin = sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr = devnull, bufsize=self.audioFrameBytes*10)

    audioFrame = audioPipe.stdout.read(self.audioFrameBytes) 

currentFrame=0;

while len(vidFrame)==self.inputVidFrameBytes:
    currentFrame+=1
    if(currentFrame%30==0):
        self.progressBarVar.set(100.0*(currentFrame*1.0)/self.totalFrames)
    if (self.videoBitDepth.get() == 16):
        output.write(vidFrame)
    else:
        b16VidFrame=bytearray(vidFrame)
        b8VidFrame=[]
        for p in range(self.outputVidFrameBytes):
            b8VidFrame.append(((b16VidFrame[(p*2)+0]>>0)&0xE0)|((b16VidFrame[(p*2)+0]<<2)&0x1C)|((b16VidFrame[(p*2)+1]>>3)&0x03))
        output.write(bytearray(b8VidFrame))

    vidFrame = vidPipe.stdout.read(self.inputVidFrameBytes) # Read where vidframe is to match up with audio frame and output?
    if (self.audioEnable.get() == 1):


        if len(audioFrame)==self.audioFrameBytes:
            audioData=bytearray(audioFrame) 

            for j in range(int(round(self.audioFrameBytes/2))):
                sample = ((audioData[(j*2)+1]<<8) | audioData[j*2]) + 0x8000
                sample = (sample>>(16-self.outputAudioSampleBitDepth)) & (0x0000FFFF>>(16-self.outputAudioSampleBitDepth))

                audioData[j*2] = sample & 0xFF
                audioData[(j*2)+1] = sample>>8

            output.write(audioData)
            audioFrame = audioPipe.stdout.read(self.audioFrameBytes)

        else:
            emptySamples=[]
            for samples in range(int(round(self.audioFrameBytes/2))):
                emptySamples.append(0x00)
                emptySamples.append(0x00)
            output.write(bytearray(emptySamples))

self.progressBarVar.set(100.0)

vidPipe.terminate()
vidPipe.stdout.close()
vidPipe.wait()

if (self.audioEnable.get() == 1):
    audioPipe.terminate()
    audioPipe.stdout.close()
    audioPipe.wait()

output.close()
```

The Rust snippet that should accomplish the same goals:

```rust
let output_file = OpenOptions::new()
    .create(true)
    .truncate(true)
    .write(true)
    .open(&output_path)
    .unwrap();
let mut writer = BufWriter::with_capacity(
    options.video_frame_bytes.max(options.audio_frame_bytes),
    output_file,
);
let ffmpeg_path = sidecar_path("ffmpeg");
#[cfg(debug_assertions)]
let timer = Instant::now();

let mut video_cmd = Command::new(&ffmpeg_path);
#[rustfmt::skip]
video_cmd.args([
    "-i", options.path,
    "-f", "image2pipe",
    "-r", options.frame_rate,
    "-vf", options.scale,
    "-vcodec", "rawvideo",
    "-pix_fmt", "bgr565be",
    "-f", "rawvideo",
    "-",
])
.stdin(Stdio::null())
.stdout(Stdio::piped())
.stderr(Stdio::null());

// windows creation flag CREATE_NO_WINDOW: stops the process from creating a CMD window
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags
#[cfg(windows)]
video_cmd.creation_flags(0x08000000);

let mut video_child = video_cmd.spawn().unwrap();
let mut video_stdout = video_child.stdout.take().unwrap();
let mut video_frame = vec![0; options.video_frame_bytes];

let mut audio_cmd = Command::new(&ffmpeg_path);
#[rustfmt::skip]
audio_cmd.args([
    "-i", options.path,
    "-f", "s16le",
    "-acodec", "pcm_s16le",
    "-ar", options.sample_rate,
    "-ac", "1",
    "-",
])
.stdin(Stdio::null())
.stdout(Stdio::piped())
.stderr(Stdio::null());

#[cfg(windows)]
audio_cmd.creation_flags(0x08000000);

let mut audio_child = audio_cmd.spawn().unwrap();
let mut audio_stdout = audio_child.stdout.take().unwrap();
let mut audio_frame = vec![0; options.audio_frame_bytes];

while video_stdout.read_exact(&mut video_frame).is_ok() {
    writer.write_all(&video_frame).unwrap();

    if audio_stdout.read_to_end(&mut audio_frame).is_ok() {
        if audio_frame.len() == options.audio_frame_bytes {
            for i in 0..options.audio_frame_bytes / 2 {
                let temp_sample = ((u32::from(audio_frame[(i * 2) + 1]) << 8)
                    | u32::from(audio_frame[i * 2]))
                    + 0x8000;
                let sample = (temp_sample >> (16 - 10)) & (0x0000FFFF >> (16 - 10));

                audio_frame[i * 2] = (sample & 0xFF) as u8;
                audio_frame[(i * 2) + 1] = (sample >> 8) as u8;
            }
        } else {
            audio_frame.fill(0x00);
        }
    }
    writer.write_all(&audio_frame).unwrap();
}


video_child.wait().unwrap();
audio_child.wait().unwrap();

#[cfg(debug_assertions)]
{
    let elapsed = timer.elapsed();
    dbg!(elapsed);
}

writer.flush().unwrap();
```

I have looked at the hex data of the files using HxD - regardless of how I alter the Rust program, I am unable to get data different from what is previewed in the attached image - so the audio pipe is incorrectly interfaced. I included a screenshot of the hex data from the working python program that converts the video and audio correctly.

HxD Python program hex output:

[image: HxD Python program hex output]

HxD Rust program hex output:

[image: HxD Rust program hex output]

Answer (score 1):

`vec![0; options.audio_frame_bytes]` does not allocate an empty buffer with capacity `options.audio_frame_bytes`, it creates a buffer full of zeros of that size. To create a vec with no data but a large underlying allocation, use `Vec::with_capacity`.

Additionally, `read_to_end` does not overwrite the buffer it is passed, it adds on to the end.

Let's pretend that audio frame size is 3 for the sake of an easy example. This is how your code functions:

```
buffer = vec![0; 3];
read_to_end(&mut buffer);
println!("{buffer:?}");
// Prints out [0, 0, 0, 90, 98, 10]

if buffer.len() == 3 {
    // Does not enter, buffer.len is 2 * options.audio_frame_bytes
} else {
    buffer.fill(0);
    println!("{buffer:?}");
    // prints out [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}
```

If you replace your vec declaration with `Vec::with_capacity` it should work

Comment: It still doesn't look like any information is being put into the `audio_frame` vector when using `Vec::with_capacity`. Each time `audio_stdout.read_to_end(&mut audio_frame)` is called, I printed out the `audio_frame` vector and it's always empty which leads me to think it's a stdio or pipe problem

Comment: @rust_convert re-reading `read_to_end` docs, it's possible you're reading a zero byte and rust is detecting it as an EOF. Maybe try creating the zero vector as you were originally, and use `read_exact` instead.

Comment: sorry, 0x05 is an EOF byte, not 0x00. If `read_to_end` sees that byte, it will stop reading

Comment: I was originally using `read_exact` as I do with the video buffer in the snippet, but it fails with `Result = Err(Error { kind: UnexpectedEof, message: "failed to fill whole buffer" })` which led me to trying other ways of reading into the buffer. The vector is filled with 0's as expected, but it looks like no new information ever enters the buffer.